# Writing to Serial Port in Odroid

Tags: java, serial-port, odroid

Is anyone writed program in JAVA on Odroid xu4 which support Serial Port communication?

In my program I want be able to write some `String`'s in Serial Port as some output from Odroid.

I have bad feelings, about handling serial ports in java and especially on Odroid / linux.

Have You same advices for me?
Should I use RxTx library for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What OS do you use? Android or Ubuntu?

AFAIK, Any serial android APP can use in XU4.

You can test the serial at terminal android, ubuntu both.

Also, why don't you go see Hardkernel's forum and wiki?

There are information for UART with XU4.

Comment: This is not an answer.